# AddAttributeToFilter is not loading specific products in Magento

Tags: php, magento

I wrote Manufacturer.php file in app/code/local/myown/layoutmods/catalog/block/product/list/
with function. Now when I try to use it loads all products. I checked and that file is called, but it wont filter by manufacturer. Thank you all for advices.

```
protected function _getProductCollection() {
        if (is_null($this->_productCollection)) {

            // Get attribute value id:
            $manufacturer_name = Mage::registry( 'current_category' )->getName();
            $productModel = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
            $attr = $productModel->getResource()->getAttribute('manufacturer');
            if ($attr->usesSource()) {
                $manufacturer_id = $attr->getSource()->getOptionId($manufacturer_name);
            }

            // load and filter product collection
            $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
            Mage::getModel('catalog/layer')->prepareProductCollection($collection);
            $collection->addStoreFilter();
            $this->_productCollection = $collection;
            $this->_productCollection->addAttributeToSelect( 'manufacturer' )->addAttributeToFilter( 'manufacturer', array( 'eq' => $manufacturer_id ) );
        } 

        return $this->_productCollection;
    }
```

Comment: I tried adding ->load() at the end of this row, but it brakes the server $this->_productCollection->addAttributeToSelect( 'manufacturer' )->addAttributeToFilter( 'manufacturer', array( 'eq' => $manufacturer_id ) );

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell the problem is not in the products collection or the filter but in $manufacturer_id parameter.

If you comment out the code between // Get attribute value id: and // load and filter product collection comments and then replace $manufacturer_id with one of the ids from the database it will work. I also had to comment out

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/layer')->prepareProductCollection($collection);
```

In my case this line prevented anything from getting into collection so I'm not certain what exactly it does.

The first problem that I see is that $manufacturer_id doesn't necessarily always get set because of

```
if ($attr->usesSource()) {
```

I wasn't able to get the code running because Mage::registry( 'current_category' ) didn't contain a value when I tested it. I'd suggest that you retest the code that you are using for retrieving manufacturer id.